# how to call web service from javascript (ajax)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have 1 project webservice and 1 project web asp.net
i want to insert data by json(ajax)
i tested file service by code behind and it good,
have error with code js
file WebService1:

```
public bool HelloWorld(student obj) {
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PHAMHOP-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=qlsv;Integrated Security=True");
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sinhvien(name,age) values(@name,@age)", cnn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", obj.name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("age", obj.age);
    int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (row == 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

file aspx:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:51097/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{'id':'1' ,'name': 'Amit', 'age': '97'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("ok");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<body>
    <input type='Button' value='gui' OnClick='add()'/>
</body>
```

It does not work.

Comment: try removing `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",`

Comment: `It does not work` will not help. Post the actual error message you are getting from the browser console.

Comment: it call function success, but not call service, bro @Singh

Answer (score 1):

Since the returned data is not `JSON` `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",` is not needed and the `data` option does not need to be a string. Pass it as an object.

Try this

```
function add() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:51097/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Amit',
            age: 97
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what does 'contentType' has to do with returned data? Isn't it to specify the data that is sent to the server rather than returned from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try passing the JSON as a string parameter instead of as a student and deserialising it yourself using Newtonsoft or System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.

```
bool HelloWorld(string obj)
```

instead of

```
bool HelloWorld(student obj)
```

Comment: `try passing the JSON as a string` - JSON **is** a string